# Android Animation Choppy on Drawables

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I've had some difficulty with animating simple ImageViews in an app. I noticed that when using the hdpi images that I had and placed in the drawable-hdpi folder, animations came out as choppy and lagged, but when they were placed in the xhdpi and xxhdpi folder, the images were scaled but came out smooth. I assume its an issue with the way I am displaying my images.

Currently there are four ImageViews in my layout that are around a similar size as the image I am animating which is 1460 x 1080 pixels. I am testing on a tablet 1920 x 1200. When three of the four images are on the screen, the animation is significantly smoother as I want it to be, but when all images are displayed, the animation is choppy and slow.

I also noticed that when testing on an emulator, the animation seemed smooth unlike when tested on a tablet (1920 x 1200).

Here is the simple animation code.

```
 TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f, -1200f, 0f, 0f);
     anim.setInterpolator(new  LinearInterpolator());
     anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
     anim.setRepeatMode(TranslateAnimation.REVERSE);
     anim.setDuration(2300);
     left.setAnimation(anim);
```

Here is the xml for my layout.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"

    />
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The probable reason why animation is smoother if you put your images in the xhdpi/xxhdpi folder on your hdpi device is, that it will get downscaled by at least 50%, so you might consider downscaling your original and using the correct drawable selector.

Second: activate hardware acceleration in your manifest, this fixes animation in most cases.

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

But mind the few differences when harware acceleration is on (see [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html))

***EDIT: Please dont mind the hardware acceleration hint: it should be on by default (this changed in recent years)***